# Trouble including files from subdirectories in Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen, eigen3

I am very new to cmake and hence could not really understand if it is appropriate to link my doubt to some existing question. In case, it is feel free to merge it to an appropriate question.

I installed the Eigen Library on my system. The include files are in /usr/local/include/eigen3 . The structure of the above directory is as follows :

```
/eigen3                                                                                     
 --------/Eigen

 ---------/unsupported           

 ---------signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library
```

In writing the CMakeLists.txt for a project I wrote using Eigen, I followed the following steps in accordance with [this answer here](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=94166) :

1. Created a folder named "cmake" in my PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR and copied FindEigen3.cmake file to it (The file was present in the /usr/local/eigen3/cmake folder. )
2. Made appropriate changes to my CMakeLists.txt as reported in the forum.

The trouble is that in one of my source files i  have a line as follows :

```
#include"Eigen/Dense"
```

When I try to run the makefile generated by CMake, I get the error that it cannot locate Eigen/Dense. I don't understand this, because Eigen/Dense is just in the EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR as found by FindEigen3.cmake 
In order to circumvent this issue I have to modify the following line in my CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

to

```
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}/Eigen)
```

Then I can simply write `#include"Dense"` and it works. What is the reason of this behavior, and is there a way to circumvent it because I have so many source files in which I will have to change such lines ? Moreover a clarification on this behavior would be helpful with any future libraries as well.

Comment: That really seems weird. Maybe try adding the failing compilation command line from `make VERBOSE=1` to the post.

Comment: Are you sure that variable `EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR` is not empty? What is the output of the command `message(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})`?